# relation between topology and space-filling curves

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, online-resources

I got a general topology course this semester, and the professor asked us to pick a subject and give a lecture about it. I was familiar with space-filling curves and after finding a part of a chapter in Munkres book about it, I picked it as my lecture subject and the professor agreed. So I started to look up for sources, books and papers, but I want a little more material so I can select the most suitable stuff from them. Can anybody suggest some books, papers, or online sources about space-filling curves which a big or small part of them involves topology?

Comment: Two books are [**Space-Filling Curves**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0387942653) by Sagan (1994) and [**Curious Curves**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/9814291285) by Darst/Palagallo/Price (2010) which together provide a large amount of material and many references (175 items for 1st book, 19 items for 2nd book). See also [this paper by Alexander Kupers](http://people.math.harvard.edu/~kupers/notes/spacefillingfunctions.pdf) and google [Hahn-Mazurkiewicz theorem](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Hahn-Mazurkiewicz+theorem%22) and [Peano space](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22peano+space%22).

Comment: @davel.renfro thanks! this is helpful!